# How does "remote tracking" work in Git?

Tags: git, git-remote

When I **clone** a repository, I can read in Git Extensions if my local version is in sync with the origin version:

[image]

When I **simply copy** a repo and define it as a remote afterwards, there is no such information.

How does this "remote tracking" work?

Comment: Maybe better to edit your question to show the specific commands you're using. If possible, I'd suggest using git in the terminal rather than a UI tool as they often abstract away the important parts of git, which leads to confusion.

Comment: yes, I meant copying the file directory. thx for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining a remote only writes a couple of lines in the configuration file of the local repo. It doesn't contact the remote repo.

You have to [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) from the remote, to let the local repo know about the branches of the remote repo.

Then you have to use [`git branch --set-upstream-to`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#git-branch---set-upstream-toltupstreamgt) to tell it that a local branch must track a remote branch.

```
git remote add origin <path-to-the-source-repo>
git fetch origin
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
```